# SQL Copy values from one table to another but move duplicates to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, duplicates

I wonder if anyone could assist me?

Within my database I have two tables which have identical columns and contain the same type of data. My first table is one we have been maintaining for the last 6 years and have a few million records in it. My second table is one we have been given from elsewhere which contains over 100 million records. It is likely that some of the data in table two is already contained in table one.

What I am trying to achieve is to add the unique records from table two in to table one.

My PK is the same for both tables, and it is this column that would identify if it is a duplicate or not.

The issue comes about, that I need to show at the end of the process the duplicate records so that these can be reviewed.

I have a good basic knowledge of SQL but not advanced enough to achieve this.
If anyone is able to assist it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `insert into one(...) select ... from two t where not exists (select * from one x where x.id = t.id)`

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
INSERT INTO Table1
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Table1 
WHERE PrimaryKeyColumn NOT IN (SELECT PrimaryKeyColumn from Table1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
-- store the duplicates
SELECT t2.id
INTO #tempTable
FROM table2 t2
JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.id = t2.id

-- insert the non-duplicates
SELECT t2.*
INTO table1
FROM table2 t2
LEFT JOIN #tempTable t1 ON t1.id = t2.id
-- Alternative to above - LEFT JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.id IS NULL

-- display the duplicates
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM #tempTable
JOIN table1 t1 ON tempTable.id = t1.id
JOIN table2 t2 ON tempTable.id = t2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into one(...) 
select ...
from two t
where not exists (
  select *
  from one x
  where x.id = t.id
  )
  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Sql 2008, Consider using Merge statement
this will insert unique keys

```
MERGE ONE AS Tar
USING (SELECT Id FROM TWO) AS Sor
ON Tar.Id=Sor.Id
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT(Id)
values(Sor.Id);
```

this will show you the duplicate keys

```
SELECT B.ID
FROM ONE A
LEFT JOIN TWO B
ON A.ID=B.ID
WHERE B.ID IS NOT NULL
```